# How to change class field type and layout when we define a new class by extending a class in Android Java?

Tags: java, android, generics, types, constructor

I want to reuse MyClass by defining a new class MyClass_B that extends MyClass.  But I need to change the class field variable 'adapter', and variable 'new_adapter' in method1 from ClassA to ClassB when I use MyClass_B. I also need to change the layout from class_a_layout to class_b_layout for MyClass_B.

I am new to Java. Is there a good way to realize this concept?

```
public class MyClass  extends AppCompatActivity {

  private ClassA   adapter ; 
  ...

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.class_a_layout);

        ...

        adapter = new ClassA(MyClass.this, var1 );
        ...
   }

   private void method1( String var2, String var3 ){ 
     ClassA   new_adapter ; 
     ....
  }

 private void  method2(...){
 ...
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Fragments inside class Activity file

https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidFragments/article.html